# How to use mod function for linq to ms access?

Tags: c#, linq, ms-access, dayofweek

I am trying to query day of week using linq and I have ms access as the database. Now I have used the following code using % (mod) to check for day of week since linq to query doesn't support `DayOfWeek`.

```cs
planQuery = planQuery.Where(x => DbFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, x.Date) % 7 
                                                                == (int)DayOfWeek.Monday && x.Date != null);
```

But the problem occurs when this code is translated to sql it looks like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myTable
where (DateDiff("d", [Datum], 1) % 7) = 1
```

Which in turn throws syntax error when I try to run it because of the %. After looking around I realized % equivalent of ms access is `mod`

So the following code runs fine. But this is not what the translated SQL look like.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myTable
where (DateDiff("d", [Datum], 1) mod 7) = 1
```

How can I use linq to query ms access using mod function?

Comment: Which client are you using to connect to MS-ACCESS? - it might be a bug :-|

Comment: @Stefan JetEntityFrameWork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulus is an operation that's easily reproduced with some division, rounding and subtraction.

```
DbFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, x.Date) - (((int)DbFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, x.Date) / 7) * 7)
```

This should be equal to `DbFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, x.Date) % 7`, at slightly higher overhead.

Comment: That's so simple and "elegant". It's kind of a hack, but I don't have to fight the bug now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why you say [DayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.8) is not functional, i wrote:

```
planQuery = planQuery.Where(x => (x.Date != null) &&
                              (DbFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, x.Date) % 7 == (int)DayOfWeek.Monday));
```

because if x.Date is null, you dont test the second part. In your code, you could have an error if x.Date is null, because you test it at the end of test.

`since linq to query doesn't support DayOfWeek`

DayofWeek is C#,  not a special linq directives

so if you want to use Linq Query syntax, the answer could be:

```
var result = from x in planQuery
             where (x.Date != null) &&
                  (DbFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, x.Date) % 7 == (int)DayOfWeek.Monday)
                     select x;
```

Comment: How does this reflect: `After looking around I realized % equivalent of ms access is mod`?

Comment: I don't see how's this is any different from my code.

Comment: if x.Date is null, you'll have an error because DBfunctions is called first in && test, in my code if x.Date is null, the test is false and the second part is not tested

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question I'm looking for. And I mentioned `linq to query` not just `linq`.

Comment: yes i have added the linq to query..and i dont see problem to use % with it.. So i suppose planQuery is IEnumerable or IQueryable collection....

Comment: That's what I tried to explain in the question. When the above LinQ gets translated to SQL query it doesn't translate the query properly. It should've used `mod` instead of `%`

Comment: sorry i am lost with what you want..you want linq query syntax or SQL syntax...i dont see and i dont have error using linq with % (mod)

Comment: your title of question speaks about mod for linq....

Comment: This is a limitation of Access EF Core provider not a Linq query itself.